# Authentication with ALB

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito, amazon-elb, aws-application-load-balancer

I need some help/advice regarding security and ALB.

I have some Lambda Functions behind an Application Load Balancer. Each Lambda is invoked based on path based routing configured in the ALB.

I'd like to implement Authentication / Authorization so that a Lambda function (in a different account) is authorized for /PATH1 only, while another Lambda function (also in a different account) is authorized for /PATH2 only.

What is the best / simplest way to achieve this. I've been trying a few things using ALB Authentication integration with Cognito. But everything I try (or find in online resources) related to the Cognito integration seems to be around user authentication using OIDC. I don't have any users in my scenario.

Also, for my use case, I can't use API Gateway.

Am I missing something silly and simple?

Thanks for any help and insight!

[image: Lambda ALB]

Answer (score 2):

I think it's possible to do what you need using AWS Cognito.

1. In AWS Cognito create a User Pool for your application. After the user pool created you can configure application integration.
2. In "General Settings" of the user pool you need to create 2 App clients - one for source lambda 1 and one for source lambda 2.
3. In "App Integration" section add a new "Resource Server" - it should be your ALB. Add 2 scopes - for path1 and path2.
4. In "App Integration" section go to App Client settings. There should be two clients created in step 2. In **Allowed OAuth Flows** select Client Credentials and related scope.
5. Share relevant client credentials to your Lambda 1 and Lambda 2.
6. Lambda 1,2 should obtain Access Token from AWS Cognito to be able to make request to ALB. [Here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/token-endpoint.html) you can find documentation on how to get access token from AWS Cognito. Lambdas should add an access token to 'Authorization' header of the request to ALB.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I tried something like this, using the Resource Server feature. I couldn't get it to work. But resource server feature is new to me, so it's likely I might have gotten something wrong. It's good to know I was on the right track. I'll try it again. Really appreciate the help!

Comment: Another quick follow-up question: I would also need an app client for the ALB itself, correct?

Comment: You need an app client for ALB only in case if ALB acts as a client of some other resource server. In this case, ALB is a resource provider/server, therefore you don't need a an app client for ALB.

Comment: hmm - I am not sure I understand or I follow. When I configure the "Authenticate" step in ALB routing rules configuration, the Cognito client requires Authorization code grant. So that means I either need to use a different client id for the ALB that has those configured, or if I use one of the Lambda 1 or Lambda 2 App Clients, they can't be configured with Client Credentials OAuth Flows.